# Increase memory allocated to jdk

Tags: java, memory-leaks, crash-reports, jvm-crash

My eclipse is pointing to a jdk. I am using GWT. sometimes my eclipse is crashing with the following error, can someone help[image]

i'm getting a new error when Xmx2000m
[image]

these are some of the last lines of the error log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2011-02-05 05:56:06.306
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'diagramMenu/filtersMenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common.myShowHideCompartmentAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2011-02-05 05:56:06.331
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'diagramMenu/filtersMenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common.myShowHideContentsAction
!SESSION 2011-02-05 05:57:13.577 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20100909-0800
java.version=1.6.0_23-ea
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product -XX:+AggressiveHeap org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product -XX:+AggressiveHeap org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2011-02-05 05:57:16.411
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2011-02-05 05:57:24.076
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'diagramMenu/filtersMenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common.myShowHideCompartmentAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2011-02-05 05:57:24.098
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'diagramMenu/filtersMenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.papyrus.diagram.common.myShowHideContentsAction
```

Comment: how do you know that this error is related to memory?

Comment: I'm just guessing because all files in my web app are ok, they run!!

Comment: Is anything being written to the eclipse error log?

Comment: when i'm getting this error, the whole eclipse is crashing, even eclipse quits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory settings for eclipse is in eclipse.ini. Increase your setting from -Xmx1000m to i.e. -Xmx2000m.

Comment: I've updated the question, i'm getting a new error when adding -Xmx2000m.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this has anything to do with memory. What eclipse version are you using? It sounds like a bug on previous Eclipse version: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324491

Answer (score 1):

Try http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/#4.2.2.%20AggressiveHeap|outline

The option -XX:+AggressiveHeap lets the vm allocate dynamically more memory.

Comment: Maybe the option -XX:MaxPermSize=600m produces the later exit code -1. You can try to omit it and ru nwith the aggressive option. But i have no idea what your exit code -2147483610 means. Maybe you should ask in the eclipse forums.